# Users getting this compile error

Tags: permissions, users, amazon-ec2

Hi I am setting up multiple users using sungrid on an EC2 cluster and have run into this error. Anyone know what it means?

/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file helloworldmpi: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

thanks

Answer (score 2):

needed to change ownership of home directory... duh...